# How can I prevent a window from being resized with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a program which creates a window where a message is displayed according to a check box.

How can I make the window size constant when the message is displayed and the message is not displayed?

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.var = IntVar()
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        f2 = Frame(master,width=200,height=100)
        f2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        button = Checkbutton(frame,text='show',variable=self.var,command=self.fx)
        button.grid(row=0,column=0)
        msg2="""I feel bound to give them full satisfaction on this point"""
        self.v= Message(f2,text=msg2)
    def fx(self):
        if self.var.get():
            self.v.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=N)
        else:
            self.v.grid_remove()

top = Tk()
app = App(top)            
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This code makes a window with the conditions that the user cannot change the dimensions of the `Tk()` window, and also disables the maximise button.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Within the program you can change the window dimensions with @Carpetsmoker's answer, or by doing this:

```
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(<widthpixels>, <heightpixels>))
```

It should be fairly easy for you to implement that into your code. :)

Comment: but, upon clicking the checkbox its position is changing in the window

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `minsize` and `maxsize` to set a minimum & maximum size, for example:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    master.minsize(width=666, height=666)
    master.maxsize(width=666, height=666)
```

Will give your window a fixed width & height of 666 pixels.

Or, just using `minsize`

```
def __init__(self,master):
    master.minsize(width=666, height=666)
```

Will make sure your window is always *at least* 666 pixels large, but the user can still expand the window.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
parentWindow.maxsize(#,#);
parentWindow.minsize(x,x);
```

At the bottom of your code to set the fixed window size.

Answer (score 2):

Below code will fix `root = tk.Tk()` to its size before it was called:

```
root.resizable(False, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of an existing solution already provided above:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

The advantage is that you type less.

Answer (score -2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkwindowwithlabel5.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "tkwindowwithlabel5.py", line 16, in main
    window.resizeable(width = True, height =True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1935, in                
  __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'resizeable'
```

is what you will get with the first answer.
tk does support min and max size

```
window.minsize(width = X, height = x)
window.maxsize(width = X, height = x)
```

i figured it out but just trying the first one. using python3 with tk.

Comment: You're trying to use the first answer with a typo. `root.resizeable(...)` gives you the above error, try `root.resizable(...)`.