# Set window dimensions in Tkinter, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've done plenty of Tkinter Python apps before, but I've never come across this problem:

How do you set the dimensions of the initial (root) window in Tkinter with Python 3?

I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958534/setting-the-window-to-a-fixed-size-with-tkinter) which details the answer for Python 2.7, but Tkinter has been updated for Python 3 so the solution doesn't work.

Here's the obnoxious bit of code:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        master.minsize(width=500,height=500)

app = Application()
app.master.title("MFPA")
app.mainloop()
```

The `master.minsize()` line comes from the referenced question, but since my `master` object is `None`, the method doesn't exist.

The second solution there also doesn't work, as it relies on having called the `tk.Tk()` method to start with, whereas I am using the updated Tkinter and this new method of creating windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tk.Frame.__init__` call should automatically find the master for you and assign it to an attribute of the object. Try:

```
    self.master.minsize(width=500,height=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
self.geometry("500x500")
```