# How to add height and width to Tkinter form

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add height of 600 and width of 600 to following form but I couldn't find any potion to do this. How can I do this?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *

app = Tkinter.Tk()
app.configure(background='black')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
app.title('Geometric Network')
app.iconbitmap(default='app.ico')
def helloCallBack():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = Tkinter.Button(app, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the window to a fixed size with Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958534/setting-the-window-to-a-fixed-size-with-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`geometry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method), you can change the size or position of top level windows:

```
app = Tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry('600x600')  # <---
...
```